# USB does not detecting in oracle virtualbox on mac OS

Tags: windows, macos, windows-8, usb, virtualbox

My operating system is window 8 and I am running mac OS in a Virtual box.I have successfully install the Mac OS on oracle Virtual box but when I used my Pen drive it's not detect in mac OS. I have install external software for USB devices for **[virtualbox extension pack 4.2.16](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)**  but my problem not solved.

Please check my screenshot's. Please Help me and solve my problem...

Thanks you.

[image: oracle VM virtualBox Settings Serial Ports Image]

I click on Add Filter form device option and select my USB then virtualbox automatic detect this information. Then I ok and run mac OS.

[image: oracle VM virtualBox Settings USB Image]

Mac Os start when i go to virtualbox menu and click option on **Devices->USB Devices->kingston Data Traveler G3[0100]**. when i faced that type of error.

Please solve my problem.

Thanks you.

[image: Error Facing for detect USB.]

Answer (score 4):

First of all format your USB  device as fat32. Then open virtual box and go to USB option and uncheck the box that says `ENABLE USB 2.0 (ECHI) CONTROLLER`. And then open mac and connect USB...
It works for me..:)

Answer (score 2):

If a USB Mass Storage device is still claimed by the host OS will not be available for your virtual operating system. I'd recommend right-clicking the drive and select Eject. Then, try to mount the drive on your virtual OS.

Answer (score 1):

I have Oracle Virtual Box installed on my Windows 8 system.  I run Windows XP in the Virtual box and occasionally have trouble with it loading my USB thumb drive. The only thing I have found that works it to remove the thumb drive and plug it into a different USB port.
I have also founnd that some USB drives work better when plugged into a USB port on the computer its self rather than plugging it into a USB hub.